# Windows Phone emulator fail to stop

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm having problem with the Windows Phone emulator.
Last night, when i have finished my works, I wanted to close it, but it didn't shut down properly.

After 10-15 minutes I shut down my computer.

But now, when I'm trying to connect to the emulator again, I can't.

I've tried many things, but it still fails.

I open the Hyper-V Maganger, and I saw that my emulator state is still "Stopping".

What can i do?